# Парсинг курса валют Visual Studio c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Подскажите пожалуйста как парсить курс валют с определённого сайта на с++ ( visual studio 2012) Windows Forms
Может быть есть книги с гайдами?

Comment: Делаете http запрос к странице с курсами, получаете html код страницы, дальше можно парсить его любыми средствами. Конкретно с данными задачами (обработка http(s) запросов и работа с xml) отлично справляется фреймворк Qt. Пример для кьюта - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-http-example.html

Comment: Если у вас жесткое условие сделать это штатными средствами системы, то WinApi также предлагает функционал для работы с http(s) запросами, описание https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385473(v=vs.85).aspx . Разбор структуры html можно реализовать самому или подключить любой xml-фреймворк (libxml и т.п.)

Comment: Спасибо за информацию